# How change the date form field according to a box that is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have four reservation boxes, one for each event that I will do, and each box has a date.
When a person clicks on a box, automatically a form appears.

What i want to do:

For example:

```
BOX ONE - DATE: 1/1/1
BOX TWO - DATE: 2/2/2
BOX THREE - DATE: 3/3/3
BOX FOUR - DATE: 4/4/4
```

If a person clicks on the box number one, the form with the date 1/1/1 selected appear. If the person clicks on the box two, the form with the date 2/2/2 selected appears.

```
<div data-dateValue="1/1/1" class="box box-1">
 <h2>Box one</h2>
 <h2>1/1/1</h2>
</div>

<div data-dateValue="2/2/2" class="box box-2">
 <h2>Box two</h2>
 <h2>2/2/2</h2>
</div>
```

And them i have a select option with the same dates:

```
<select>
 <option>1/1/1</option>
 <option>1/1/1</option>
</select>
```

I need change the option selected according to the box that the user clicked.

Comment: Can you post a complete code example, specifically all the relevant HTML?

Comment: I update the code, I'm not very good at explaining, but I think now I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't see the entire html so it's difficult to make a proper selector for the option but it will look like this :

```
$('.box').on('click', function(){
     var s = $(this).data('dateValue');
     $("option").data('dateValue', s).val(s);   
});
```

**UPDATE**

If i understand properly the code will look like this :

```
$('.box').on('click', function(){
     var s = $(this).data('dateValue');
     $("select").val(s);   
});
```

That will select the option in the select that contains the value selected on the box.

Comment: I update the code, I'm not very good at explaining, but I think now I got it.